# Width of source control text display... How to fix?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

In Xcode 12, this is what my source control navigator looks like. Xcode 11 and earlier didn't chop off or compress the column width as you see here. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image: Xcode 12 running dark mode on Catalina.]

Comment: File a bug report. File it NOW because they could go final real soon. (Meanwhile, my solution: don't use Xcode git integration. It has always sucked.)

Comment: Ok. I filed a radar. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is a totally reasonable complaint.

Comment: It's in public Xcode 12 :(

Comment: As a regular source control user from Xcode, I find this so frustrating. How come it came to GM even after multiple beta.

Comment: It is still in xcode 12 prod and is really frustating..

Comment: In the AppStore version 12.0.1 (12A7300) the issue hasn't been solved yet.

Comment: Not fixed even in Xcode 12.0.1

Comment: Not fixed in 12.1 GM Seed.

Comment: There's no way Apple didn't notice this. I'm guessing their analytics tell them that not many devs are using that feature, so it was low-priority.
FWIW, you can get the fill branch name by hovering over the title.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be corrected using Xcode 12.2 beta (12B5018i) on Catalina 10.15.6