# Xcode 12 source control UI truncating git branch names

Tags: xcode, git, xcode12

As the title says, the Xcode 12 UI is no longer displaying git branch names in their entirety.  It used to be that under the source control navigator tab Xcode would list of the names with as many characters as possible, for example:

```
sprint_17_home_button_fix
sprint_17_double_entry_fix
sprint_18_added_color_change
```

Now it's truncating the middle of each branch with an ellipsis:

```
s...ix
s...ix
s...ge
```

This makes it super difficult to traverse my branches. Does anyone know if there are any settings where I can address this issue? Everything I search is about git itself not functioning, which is not my issue.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Can the pane be expanded?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696576/width-of-source-control-text-display-how-to-fix this is fixed in the next beta.