# Xcode 12 the name of branches are not full visible

Tags: xcode12

In Xcode 11 the name of branches were full showed, but after I update to Xcode 12 the branches are shorted (see the screenshots below) which is not comfortable to see. How to expand them to see the full name of branches?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpsFa.jpg)

Comment: It’s a bug. Please file feedback with Apple.

Comment: Copy of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63696576/width-of-source-control-text-display-how-to-fix